# How to print out the hexadecimal content of one text using Perl binmode?

Tags: perl, binmode

Can someone tell me how **binmode** in Perl can be used to achieve the same function as following one-liner, so as to print out the hex data of one text ?

```
$ perl -nle 'print map {sprintf "%02X",ord} split //'
```

For example, if I input "abcABC", the output will be "616263414243".

Please give a similar one-liner using binmode.

Thanks.

Comment: presumably you want to read binary data?

Answer (score 0):

`binmode` would be of no use at doing what you asked. There are currently no PerlIO layers that convert all output bytes but `0A` to their ASCII hex representation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to do that from within a program? The default input mode is the same as `binmode` on Linux, and on Windows the only difference is that every CR LF is converted to LF.

So you can safely write this.

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    printf '%02X, $_ for split //;
    print "\n";
}
```

with the proviso that the CR characters will disappear if you are reading a Windows file using a Windows version of perl

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your insistance on using `binmode`, but perhaps this is what you mean?

```
perl -le 'print map { sprintf q{%02X}, ord } split //, shift' abcABC
```

#### output

```
616263414243
```